# Smarty - include subpages to main page

Tags: php, smarty

I have default template file (main.tpl) and I want to include subpages between `<body>` tags.

So when user clicks for expample on link News, it'll show news.php ($smarty->display("news.tpl");) combined with main.tpl

--> 1st part of main.tpl + news.tpl + 2nd part of main.tpl.

News.tpl would contain some text and php code, nothing else. Eg.

```
Hello, <php echo $username ?>. Some random text.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP assign template name to smarty variable:

```
$smarty->assign('module', 'news');
$smarty->display('main.tpl');
```

In main.tpl just include module template:

```
<body>{include file="$module.tpl"}</body>
```

You can find more about `{include}` smarty function here: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.include.tpl

Comment: @Miso i wonder why none of you did notice `News.tpl would contain  php code` part

Answer (score 0):

You should just `$smarty->display("main.tpl")`, and include the news.tpl in your main.tpl.

Answer (score 0):

If your templates contain PHP code, you don't need Smarty at all. Just `include` your template file.